# d3 brush not resetting when removed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

Something is missing here, since when brush is removed (you click on the brush rather than drag)? The active selection doesn't reset (ie. brush is not removed).

Any ideas how to address that?

Cheers!

```
// Handles a brush event, toggling the display of foreground lines.
function brush_parallel_chart() {    
    for(var i=0;i<dimensions.length;++i){
        if(d3.event.target==y[dimensions[i]].brush) {
            extents[i]=d3.event.selection.map(y[dimensions[i]].invert,y[dimensions[i]]);
        }
    }

    foreground.style("display", function(d) {
        return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
            if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
                return true;
            }
            return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
        }) ? null : "none";
    });
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/RkWBgQ6oi584H3212WrM?p=preview

This happens when we completely clear the brush at start:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked your code. Look at this - http://plnkr.co/edit/oYhx6DSjQHI3E3nmE97h?p=preview
Is it behavior what you need?

```
g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .each(function(d) {
    d3.select(this).call(y[d].brush = d3.brushY().extent([[-8, 0], [8,height]])
    .on("start", brushstart) // <-- !!
    .on("brush", gobrush)
    .on("brush", brush_parallel_chart));
  })
  .selectAll("rect")
  .attr("x", -8)
  .attr("width", 16);
```

I renamed you `brushstart` function to `gobrush`. And created new `brushstart` function. I attach new `brushstart` function on selection start event. In this function, I set appropriate styles, which reset selection.

```
function brushstart(selectionName) {
  foreground.style("display", "none")

  var dimensionsIndex = dimensions.indexOf(selectionName);

  extents[dimensionsIndex] = [0, 0];

  foreground.style("display", function(d) {
    return dimensions.every(function(p, i) {
        if(extents[i][0]==0 && extents[i][0]==0) {
            return true;
        }
      return extents[i][1] <= d[p] && d[p] <= extents[i][0];
    }) ? null : "none";
  });
}
```

Comment: But what happens is that all brush selections get reset. What if I had two brushes applied and only removed one, the filtering still should account for the other one remaining.Please look at the image that I just posted.

Comment: @konrad Oh, I did not notice that it is possible, at the same time set two or more selection. I updated the answer, look at the new link on plnkr.